# How to use SimpleMembership with WebForm 4.5 and EntityFramework?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-membership, webforms, asp.net-4.5, simplemembership

Ive heard there new providers with ASP.NET 4.5 (such membership provider) but it seem i can't find anything decent about using the SimpleMembership with WebForm ASP.NET 4.5 and EntityFramework. Is there any good documentation or explanation about how to implement the SimpleMembership with the technologies specified over (sql shema creation, configuring the project)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recent article that gives a good overview:

[SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement simple membership with webforms but you will not be able to take advantage of the login controls etc as the simplemembership provider does not implement all of the methods of membership provider. the recommendation would be to use universal providers for webforms